# example on how and when to use focus in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, ref

I see many questions on how to use focus() on a ref in react, but I seem to miss the general understanding of how and when exactly should I use focus.

can anyone offer an example?

I read https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html and still missing the point

thanks!

Comment: It's one of those things that if you don't understand *why* you should do it, then you shouldn't do it. There will come a time when you want to force focus on an element, and when that time comes, it will all make more sense.

Comment: Hi @daph.kaplan, I would like to help you but I don't quite understand your question... The cases where you have to use focus are independent from the library/framework that you are using. So, what do you want to know: valid cases of using focus (in general)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

`ref` are used to reference an element's DOM, therefore you must have the `ref` attribute for that element set, since we are going to be accessing it outside of the `render` method.

Ref is created using `React.createRef()` method provided by the react library.

Let's suppose that you want to focus on email address of a form when you load your login page, the page has render method as

```
render() {
  return (
    <form>
      <input id="email" type="email" />
      <input id="password" type="password" />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

and since you want to set the focus on the email field when the page loads, therefore you are going to use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook.

But before that we need to create a ref

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.inputElement = React.createRef();
}
```

and then assign the reference to the email input

```
<input id="email" type="email" ref={this.inputElement} />
```

finally we would focus the email when the page loads

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.inputElement.current.focus();
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer! this answer should be excepted!